The filter query in Elasticsearch returns a result that satisfies only one of the match queries in the filter array
I am using the text_en_search analyzer with the following configuration to fetch results in OpenSearch:
"text_en_search": {
  "filter": ["lowercase", "synonym_en", "stopword_en", "porter_stem"],
  "type": "custom",
  "tokenizer": "standard"
}


However, when I write a filter query with multiple match queries, I get results that match only one of the match queries. Here is the relevant part of my query:
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
      {
        "match": {
          "title_extended": {
            "query": "a",
            "operator": "OR",
            "prefix_length": 0,
            "max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "lenient": false,
            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "title_extended": {
            "query": "maruti",
            "operator": "OR",
            "prefix_length": 0,
            "max_expansions": 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "lenient": false,
            "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
    "boost": 1
  }
}


Despite expecting the filter array to operate with an implicit AND operation, some of the results only match "a".
Could you please provide a solution to resolve this issue?
Note: This is not the complete query but the main snippet that performs the logic.
I am expecting results that match both of the match queries, as all match queries should work with an implicit AND operation inside the filter array.

Can you share a sample document? And please explain the expected results with example.

Indeed, the content of the title_extended field for the document that matches both queries would be really helpful here.
